# Android (Java) network programming resources

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I would like to develop an application for Android which would transfer data through TCP connection.

Does anyone know for any good example or book where client-server connection example could be found?

I'm quite new with Java and Android so I would be very thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to believe that this question has not been answered for more than 4 years.
If somebody still needs networking examples, Android Training provides reasonable introduction to the topic.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few links to help you get started..

http://osamashabrez.com/simple-client-server-communication-in-android/
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html
http://www.androidph.com/2008/10/android-networking-user-experience-and.html

I would also recommend you to have a look at the developer.Android documentation!

Answer (score 1):

This online tutorial may be helpful: http://www.coreservlets.com/android-tutorial/ . It has 2 chapters on network programming : `Networking I: General Techniques` and `Networking II: HTTP and JSON Techniques`. You may look at the first part.