# Programming Resources on using Android Networking APIs

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn how to use Networking API in Android (or how to make the app network enabled).

I looked in the following places:
1. Coder-Darcey book "Android: wireless application development" has a short chapter on this. But it is for an older version, 1.5, of Android. I'd like to refer to a more recent & more detailed information.
2. Strangely the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com)  site has nothing at all on this.
3. Searched SOF on this, & found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623533/android-java-network-programming-resources). The link it refers to is WAY too complex for me to understand.

Anyone happen to know a good reference/website/tutorial for this important topic?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you been by "network enabled"?  You probably don't find many Android specific resources because its realy not that different from your typical java program.

Comment: The Java Tutorial - Custom networking: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html

Comment: Thanks Mayra, mrrtnn, That's quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't very different until honeycomb - but then they stopped you from making network calls in the main thread.

Making a receive thread is pretty simple - but a tutorial is really in order for a decent send thread - ensuring no syncronisation issues between adding stuff to send and sending it....

--
found a work around for the "network in main thread" check... http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html#networkoverview_apis