# connection between Android and windows 7

Tags: android, windows, tcp, connection

I want to do android application. using windows server and client is android. application send to message from android to server and server save that message to sql.in android i want to see message to which come to me.have you got any example for sending messege to server from android.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very broad. You did not specify with what language you want to program your server.

As a start you should create simple Android TCP Client and simple TCP server.
Look at this threads: 
[Android (Java) network programming resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623533/android-java-network-programming-resources), 
http://www.anddev.org/socket_programming-t325.html to get basic information on topic.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have no Idea (yet) as how to make a connection. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but that might mean you are not a really experienced programmer, and your question here implies some sort of time-pressure or at least not the willingness to dive too deeply into the material.

Therefore I'd suggest you take the 'easy' route, that might not be the most efficient in all cases, but would be usefull enough for a number of things.

- use a webserver and some files (php?) that can add rows to the database when they are requested.
- call these pages in your application trough standard HTTP.

Both of these steps are easy to graps as a concept, and you can find the how and why a lot easier if you understand the method.
No real catches here.