# Android Network programming

Tags: android

Where can I learn about network programming in android? I am writing an application which has to communicate over the wifi connection.

Answer (score 1):

To my point of view it's better to read the following sources. In the [first](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) there is an example of client and server for android using sockets. I've tried this several times so I know that the approach in this article is working. In the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623533/android-java-network-programming-resources) link you can find links to other resources.

Answer (score 0):

For tutorial on http client, see http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html
Mostly I have learned from the examples at http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial